# Django Graphene Relay order_by (OrderingFilter)

Tags: django, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have a Graphene interface with Relay and filters. It works pretty well but I would like to add the order_by options. My objects look like:

```
    class FooGQLType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        exclude_fields = ('internal_id',)
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)
        filter_fields = {
            "id": ["exact"],
            "code": ["exact", "icontains"],
        }
        connection_class = ExtendedConnection

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    foo = DjangoFilterConnectionField(FooGQLType)
```

ExtendedConnection should not be relevant but:

```
class ExtendedConnection(graphene.Connection):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    total_count = graphene.Int()

    def resolve_total_count(root, info, **kwargs):
        return root.length
```

This allows me to query like `foo(code_Icontains:"bar")`.
According to [the Graphene documentation](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/filtering/#ordering) I should be using the OrderingFilter in a FilterSet for that. I find it a bit annoying since the filters are supposed to be automatic but if I do:

```
    class FooGQLFilter(FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo

    order_by = OrderingFilter(
        fields=(
            ('code', 'code'),
            ('lastName', 'last_name'),
            ('otherNames', 'other_names'),
        )
    )
```

I get an error that I need to provide `fields` or `exclude`:

```
AssertionError: Setting 'Meta.model' without either 'Meta.fields' or 'Meta.exclude' has been deprecated since 0.15.0 and is now disallowed. Add an explicit 'Meta.fields' or 'Meta.exclude' to the FooGQLFilter class.
```

So if I add a `fields = []` to silence it, it compiles.
However, when I use it in:

```
foo = DjangoFilterConnectionField(FooGQLType, filterset_class=FooGQLFilter)
```

My regular filters like `code_Icontains` vanish. I could add them again over there but it's silly. From a quick look at the source, it looks like Relay or django-filters already created a FilterSet class (makes sense) and overwriting it this way is obviously a poor idea.

How do I add the orderBy filter on my Graphene Relay filtered objects ? I feel like this should be pretty straightforward but I am struggling to figure this out.

I have also seen examples subclassing `DjangoFilterConnectionField` with a `connection_resolver` that injects the order_by somehow but that tells me that there is no orderBy parameter.

Comment: What if you set `fields = '__all__'` in the `Meta`?

Comment: `fields = '__all__'` actually uses the default filters so `code_Icontains` doesn't exist, only `code`. If I move the `filter_fields` to the `FilterSet` fields and set `filter_fields = FooGQLFilter._meta.fields`, the filtering works but the order_by doesn't work anymore. And I don't see how to add the order_by to that in this situation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This solution only works with django-graphene until 2.6.0, see Alok Ramteke's solution for more recent versions

I have adapted a solution from [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/251) on this topic:

````
from graphene_django.filter import DjangoFilterConnectionField
from graphene.utils.str_converters import to_snake_case


class OrderedDjangoFilterConnectionField(DjangoFilterConnectionField):
    """
    Adapted from https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/251
    Substituting:
    `claims = DjangoFilterConnectionField(ClaimsGraphQLType)`
    with:
    ```
    claims = OrderedDjangoFilterConnectionField(ClaimsGraphQLType,
        orderBy=graphene.List(of_type=graphene.String))
    ```
    """
    @classmethod
    def connection_resolver(cls, resolver, connection, default_manager, max_limit,
                            enforce_first_or_last, filterset_class, filtering_args,
                            root, info, **args):
        filter_kwargs = {k: v for k, v in args.items() if k in filtering_args}
        qs = filterset_class(
            data=filter_kwargs,
            queryset=default_manager.get_queryset(),
            request=info.context
        ).qs
        order = args.get('orderBy', None)
        if order:
            if type(order) is str:
                snake_order = to_snake_case(order)
            else:
                snake_order = [to_snake_case(o) for o in order]
            qs = qs.order_by(*snake_order)
        return super(DjangoFilterConnectionField, cls).connection_resolver(
            resolver,
            connection,
            qs,
            max_limit,
            enforce_first_or_last,
            root,
            info,
            **args
        )
````

To use it, just adapt the Query from:

```
claims = DjangoFilterConnectionField(ClaimsGraphQLType)
```

to

```
claims = OrderedDjangoFilterConnectionField(ClaimsGraphQLType,
        orderBy=graphene.List(of_type=graphene.String))
```

And you can then query:

```
{ claims(status: 2, orderBy: "-id") { id } }
```

or

```
{ claims(status: 2, orderBy: ["creationDate", "lastName"]) { id } }
```

Answer (score 7):

Eric's solution won't work with the current graphene-django version(2.9.1) or greater than graphene-django 2.6.0 version.

DjangoFilterConnectionField methods are changed in the 2.7.0 version.
For more details, you can check the changelogs [here](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/releases/tag/v2.7.0)

With Eric's solution, it will generate error,
`connection_resolver() missing 1 required positional argument: 'info’`

So I have modified the solution and it worked perfectly.

```
from graphene_django.filter import DjangoFilterConnectionField
from graphene.utils.str_converters import to_snake_case


class OrderedDjangoFilterConnectionField(DjangoFilterConnectionField):

    @classmethod
    def resolve_queryset(
        cls, connection, iterable, info, args, filtering_args, filterset_class
    ):
        qs = super(DjangoFilterConnectionField, cls).resolve_queryset(
            connection, iterable, info, args
        )
        filter_kwargs = {k: v for k, v in args.items() if k in filtering_args}
        qs = filterset_class(data=filter_kwargs, queryset=qs, request=info.context).qs

        order = args.get('orderBy', None)
        if order:
            if type(order) is str:
                snake_order = to_snake_case(order)
            else:
                snake_order = [to_snake_case(o) for o in order]
            qs = qs.order_by(*snake_order)
        return qs
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that either a custom `filterset_class` must be declared and provided when using the field, or the type being used must have a `filter_fields` declaration in its `Meta` class. Otherwise an error will be thrown stating an  `AssertionError`. The original question has this, it is just missing in these answers and I thought I'd help anyone running into the same issue I did.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is still required using >3.0? The documented behavior doesn't work for me and neither does this solution as-is.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I believe I have a simple and easy answer for dealing with orderBy especially as a list in graphene. The reason I'm answering is not because I believe I have the smartest solution, I just would like to know what the difference is if I could be doing harm unknowingly. I actually don't understand the connections stuff in graphene_django so I took a different route inspired from watching this talk about ordering object in GraphQL.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDxUu-K2qdE

So first With your `FooType` I've added the fields as enums

```
class FooGQLType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo

class FooFields(graphene.Enum):
    CODE = "code"
    LAST_NAME = "last_name"
    OTHER_NAMES = "other_names"

class Directions(graphene.Enum):
    ASC = "asc"
    DESC = "desc"
```

Then an input to pass them on in the `Query`

```
class FooOrderByInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    order_by = FooFields()
    direction = Directions()
```

I wasn't sure about what you wanted to filter by but since the question was primarily about `order_by`, I just assumed it was a random string for now. I feel like there's a way to make this one line of db requests but I'm not sure how.

```
ORDER_BY = 'order_by'
DIRECTION = 'direction'

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    foo = graphene.Field(FooGQLType, input=graphene.List(FooOrderByInput), filter_opt=graphene.String())

    def resolve_foo(self, info, input):
        qs = Foo.objects.filter(filter_opt=filter_opt)
        for obj in input:
            order_by = obj.get(ORDER_BY)
            direction = "-" if obj.get(DIRECTION) == Directions.DESC else ""
            qs = qs.order_by(f"{direction}{order_by}")

        return  qs
```

The best thing about this (for me anyway) is it allows for queries on multiple fields like

```
query ($input: [FooOrderByInput]) {
  foo (input: $input) {
    id
    code
    lastName
    otherNames
  }
}

VARIABLES
{
    "input": [
        {
            "orderBy": "LAST_NAME",
            "direction": "DESC"
        },
        {
            "orderBy": "CODE",
            "direction": "ASC"
        }
    ]
}
```

And also it wont allow for anything else except those keywords spelled correctly and all. It also doesn't have to deal with camelCase to snake_case.

Please if there is a better solution or if mine sucks let me know. I'm happy this seem to be resolved anyway!