# Django relay graphql order by created date

Tags: django, graphql, relay

How to query a model as order by created date in django graphene-relay

```
class CategoryNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        filter_fields = ['name', 'ingredients', 'created_at']
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )



class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
     category = relay.Node.Field(CategoryNode)
     all_categories = DjangoFilterConnectionField(CategoryNode)
```

Comment: Have you tired adding `ordering = ['-created_at']` in your Meta class ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Graphene Relay order\_by (OrderingFilter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478464/django-graphene-relay-order-by-orderingfilter)

Comment: isn't that for the old version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution after going through the Graphene-Django documentation
https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/filtering/

Need to create a filterset for the model:

```
from django_filters import FilterSet, OrderingFilter

class CategoryFilter(FilterSet):
class Meta:
    model = Category
    fields = '__all__'

    order_by = OrderingFilter(
               fields=(('created_at'),))

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    category = relay.Node.Field(CategoryNode)
    all_categories = DjangoFilterConnectionField(CategoryNode, filterset_class=CategoryFilter)

def resolve_category(self, info, **kwargs):
    return CategoryFilter(kwargs).qs
```